# GIF loses mime type with Apache rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, rewrite, mime-type

Got problem with a gif that loses it's animation with the rewrites I'm doing.

```
RewriteRule ^journal/(.+)\.(jpeg|jpg|png|mp4|webm|ogv)$ app/uploads/journal/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^journal/(.+)\.(gif)$ app/uploads/journal/$1 [QSA,L,T=image/gif]
```

For some reason it still serves with image/jpeg headers. Any ideas why?

[**Rewrite Log**](http://pastie.org/private/o3kri3dbloc70ehydlg8g)

Comment: In the directory where you keep the files, do they have filenames ending with `.gif` and `.jpg`? Because you're stripping those out from the request.

Comment: @JennyD It could happen that both `.jpg` and `.gif` exist with the same filename in the same location, but not in this case. For reference `RewriteRule ^journal/(.+) app/uploads/journal/$1 [QSA,L]` works splendidly, but I need to be able to filter.

Comment: With the rules in the question I can't working animation at /journal/animation.gif, but if I go to /app/uploads/journal/animation.gif it works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you add the second match, to catch the filename ending, you are forgetting to attach that match to the rewrite. The first parenthesis `$1`, which you're adding on the rewrite side, but that one no longer contains the `.gif`, `.jpg` etc because they are outside the parenthesis. Instead, they end up in `$2`.

So try rewriting the rules to

```
RewriteRule ^journal/(.+)\.(jpeg|jpg|png|mp4|webm|ogv)$ app/uploads/journal/$1.$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^journal/(.+)\.(gif)$ app/uploads/journal/$1.$2 [QSA,L,T=image/gif]
```

Comment: And that of course makes total sense, thanks alot Jenny!

Comment: I'm glad I could help!